# Lexical Analysis in GCC for C language

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, gcc4.7

I am looking for the lexical analyzer code in GCC for C language but unable to find. I found lex.c but the comment inside the file says it works for C++.

Please provide any link(If available) which can help.

Answer (score 2):

The parser is reading a stream of tokens from the preprocessor, in directory `libcpp/`

Read the documentation and slides available on the [GCC resource center (IIT Bombay, India)](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/)

If you wish to extend GCC, consider using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

<sup>BTW, use a more recent version of GCC, e.g. 4.9</sup>